# How is the drift velocity affected when a conducter is cut in half?

Tags: electromagnetism

Current *I* passes through a conductor of resistance *R* when voltage *V* is applied through it.

If the conductor is cut in half, and the same voltage is applied. (which changes the length from *L* to *L/2* and thus the resistance from *R* to *R/2* AND changes the number of atoms from *N* to *N/2*), how is the drift velocity 
affected?

I know that drift velocity is related to current as,

$$ I = NAqv$$

$$\implies v= \frac{I}{NAq} $$

$$\implies v= \frac{V}{NAqR}$$

$$ \because N' = N/2 , R' = R/2 \implies v' =   \frac{V}{\frac{N}{2}Aq\frac{R}{2}} \implies v' = 4v$$

It appears to me that I am over accounting by halving both *R* and *N*, but I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: In this situation, are you holding current constant, or is the voltage constant? The double-counting probably comes from the fact that you're allowing both to vary.

Comment: @probably_someone Clarified, voltage is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first expression for current is wrong. It should be $I=nqAv$, where $n$ is the number of electrons **per unit volume**. This does not change as the wire is cut in half.

Comment: n is not the number of atoms per unit volume but the number of carriers (electrons) per unit volume. In some cases (copper for example) the two numbers are the same but this is not a general rule. There are metals with 2 or 3 free electrons for each atoms. So "n" may be larger than the concentration of atoms by a factor of 2 or 3.

Comment: Edited. Sorry, didn't realize I did that.

Answer (score 1):

The N in you formula is not the number of atoms but the concentration of charge carriers (free electrons for metals). This does not change when you cut the wire. It is a material property. You double the current density, you double the drift velocity.